# MySQL partition contains more records than expected

Tags: mysql, partitioning

I have partitioned a MySQL table containing 53 rows. Now when I query number of records in all partitions, the records are almost 3 times the expected. Even phpMyAdmin thinks there are 156 records.

Have I done somthing wrong in my table design and partitioning?

[image: Count of records]

Below picture shows count of records in partitions:

[image: Number of records in each partition]

phpMyAdmin:

[image: phpMyAdmin number of records]

Finally, this is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE cl_inbox (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  user int(11) NOT NULL,
  contact int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  sdate timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  body text NOT NULL,
  userstatus tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1 COMMENT '0: new, 1:read, 2: deleted',
  contactstatus tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  class tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  attachtype tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  attachsrc varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id, user),
  INDEX i_class (class),
  INDEX i_contact_user (contact, user),
  INDEX i_contactstatus (contactstatus),
  INDEX i_user_contact (user, contact),
  INDEX i_userstatus (userstatus)
)
ENGINE = INNODB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 69
AVG_ROW_LENGTH = 19972
CHARACTER SET utf8
COLLATE utf8_general_ci
ROW_FORMAT = DYNAMIC
PARTITION BY KEY (`user`)
(
PARTITION partition1 ENGINE = INNODB,
PARTITION partition2 ENGINE = INNODB,
PARTITION partition3 ENGINE = INNODB,
.....
PARTITION partition128 ENGINE = INNODB
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those numbers are approximations, just as with `SHOW TABLE STATUS` and `EXPLAIN`.

Meanwhile, you will probably find that `PARTITION BY KEY` provides no performance improvement.  If you find otherwise, I would be very interested to hear about it.

Comment: Thanks. My main problem is the huge amount of records I have (up to terabytes). So partitioning is mostly done to avoid problems with file sizes. Would other partitioning option increase performance? (I guess you need to see my queries to answer that?)

Comment: @wmac - Yes, I need to see queries.  It sounds like you have lots of "users" and each bucket (partition) contains lost of users?  Do 'all' of your queries include `AND user = 12345`?  You say "file size" is a problem; please elaborate on that, too.  How many rows are you expecting?  The `CREATE` provided shows a limit of 2 billion.